# Rectangular to Spherical and Cylindrical Points

Tags: calculus

Let P be the point with rectangular coordinates $(-1,-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)$. How can I find the cylindrical coordinates and the spherical coordinates of the point P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cylindrical Coordinates:**

Cylindrical coordinates have a radius and angle $r$ and $\theta$ (usually measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis) corresponding to the Cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$, and a height $h$ corresponding to the Cartesian coordinate $z$. Basically we convert the first two coordinates to polar form and then add a height component.

To find $r$, we need to find the distance of $\left(-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ from the origin $(0,0)$. This is $$r=\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
To find $\theta$, we realize that the point $\left(-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is in the third quadrant and that we can use a right triangle to find the angle over $180^\circ$. Using the fact that the tangent function of an angle is opposite over adjacent, we have that the extra angle is $\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Hence $\theta=180^\circ+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, or $\theta=\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ if you are using radians instead of degrees.

Finally, the height is just the same as the $z$-coordinate, so we have
$$(r,\theta,h)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2},\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

**Spherical Coordinates:**

Spherical coordinates have a radius $r$ and two angles $\theta$ and $\rho$, where $\theta$ corresponds to our angle $\theta$ in cylindrical coordinates, and $\rho$ corresponds to the angle between the point and the positive $z$ axis as measured from the origin.

In this case we have to recompute $r$ because this radius is from the point $\left(-1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$ to the origin $(0,0,0)$ (this is in $3$ dimensions where as in cylindrical coordinates we just used the radius in $2$ dimensions).
$$r=\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{8}{4}}=\sqrt{2}$$

$\theta$ is the same as before, so we are just left with the computation of $\rho$. Again we can use a right triangle, except this time one side of it will be the $r$ we found in the cylindrical coordinates, and the other side will be the height. First we note that the angle is greater than $90^\circ$, so we can compute the piece of the angle that is bigger than $90^\circ$ and then add it. Again we just use the $tan$ relation and calculate the extra angle as $\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)=\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)$. Hence $\rho=90^\circ+\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)$ if you are using radians instead of degrees.

Finally we have

$$(r,\theta,\rho)=\left(\sqrt{2},\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)\right)$$